How do we derive the standard cross entropy loss from negative log likelihood in a supervised (conditional) learning setting?
I know that when optimizing neural networks (supervised) that cross entropy loss is equivalent to negative log likelihood is euivalent to MLE but I can't get all the math together.
I am trying to figure out hot to get from the negative log likelihood (NLL) to cross entropy loss (CE) for supervised learning using conditional probabilities. How do you get from $\log q(y_n|x_n, \omega)$ to $y_n \log \hat{y}_n$ ?
The following notation is according to Murphy's book 'Probabilistic Machine Learning:

An introduction': There is a probabilistic model $q(D, \omega)$ for supervised learning from a dataset $D=\{(x_n, y_n)_{n=1}^N\}$ with $N$ samples ($\omega$ are the parameters)
$$
    q(\omega|X,Y) = \frac{q(Y|X,\omega)\cdot q(\omega)}{q(Y|X)}
$$
and empirical distribution (series of delta functions or “spikes” at the observed training points)
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
p_D(x,y) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \delta(x-x_n) \delta(y-y_n), \\
\delta(x) =     \begin{cases}
      \infty & \text{if } x = 0\\
      0 & \text{if } x \neq 0 
    \end{cases}, \quad \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)dx = 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$
In the book Murphy derives the NLL from the expected value of the Kullbach-Leibler divergence.
\begin{align}
\hat{\omega} &= \arg \min_\omega \mathbb{E}_{p_D (x)} [ D_{KL} (p_D(Y|x)||q(Y|x, \omega)] \\
&= \arg \min_\omega -\sum_x p_D (x) \cdot \sum_y p_D(y|x) \log q(y|x, \omega) \quad \textit{(dropped const entropy)}\\
&= \arg \min_\omega -\sum_{x,y} p_D (x,y) \log q(y|x, \omega)\\
(&= \arg \min_\omega -\sum_{n=1}^N \underbrace{p_D (x_n,y_n)}_{=\textit{const}} \log q(y_n|x_n, \omega) \quad \textit{(this line is not in the book))}\\
&= \arg \min_\omega - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \underbrace{\log q(y_n|x_n, \omega)}_{\textit{this seems to be $y_n \log \hat{y}_n$, but how?}}  \quad \text{is NLL}
\end{align}


This is what I tried:
$$
p_D(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \delta(x-x_n)
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\omega} &= \arg \min_\omega \mathbb{E}_{p_D (x)} [ D_{KL} (p_D(Y|x)||q(Y|x, \omega)] \\
&= \arg \min_\omega -\sum_x p_D (x) p_D(Y|x) \log q(Y|x, \omega) \quad \textit{(dropped const entropy)}\\
&= \arg \min_\omega -\sum_{n=1}^N \underbrace{p_D(x_n)}_{=const} \underbrace{p_D(Y|x_n)}_{=y_n?} \log \underbrace{q(Y|x_n, \omega)}_{=\hat{y}_n?}
\end{align}

Questions:

Is that correct? And if yes did I get the notation right (small and big letters)?
Why would you take the expected value of the KLD instead of using plain KLD?
I understand that $q(y|x_n, \omega)$ is the model output $\hat{y_n}$ for input $x_n$ but how do you compute $q(y_n|x_n, \omega)$? - which to my understanding is the likelihood that my model actually predicts the true label.


This looks overly complicated just write down the likelihood and then take the logarithm, the cross entropy loss will follow in 2 steps

I totally agree that this looks overly complicated but I'm not sure about the rest. This seem to be exactly my question :)
I woukd expect the following $-\sum y \log \hat{y} = - \sum p(y|x) \log q(y|x,\omega)$ but the NLL is given by  $-\sum p(y_n|x_n, \omega)$
